# change-set file in drools-workbench6.1.0?

Tags: drools, jbpm, drools-guvnor

There was a change-set file in guvnor ?

where is change-set file is located in new release kie-drools-wb-distribution-ars-6.1.0.Final-tomcat7.0

Example guvnor change-set.xml

```
<change-set xmlns='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set'
     xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
     xs:schemaLocation='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd' >

<add>
     <resource source='http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/Analytics/LATEST.drl' type='DRL' basicAuthentication="enabled" username="admin" password="admin"/>
</add>
</change-set>
```

i want to set some maven authentication parameters

example -

```
basicAuthentication="enabled" username="admin"  password="admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but as far as I remember there are no change sets in drools 6. Now we work with Kjars and their internal maven version of the artefact. There is no need for you to create change set anymore.

Comment: Ahh . . but i face 401 error while accessing artifact URL . . and unfortunately the solution for this error is include username and password in change-set in guvnor . . but in drools 6.0.x i dont know ? how can i access my kie-workbench deployed jar without 401 error. . !

Answer (score 0):

The kjars are located and exposed as a maven repo, you need to add a settings.xml (in your home folder or by referencing it as a Java system property, you can find an example here:
https://github.com/krisv/jbpm-evaluation-examples/blob/master/kjar-from-guvnor/settings.xml

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir but "(in your home folder or by referencing it as a Java system property)" can you please explain this little bit more.